# How to deploy RMI Server in Google App Engine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, rmi

I have built applications with Java RMI, but ran as a service on a windows machine. The goal now is to migrate to Google App Engine, but I have no idea how I will implement this, can someone help me?

Or is it only possible to deploy the application developed with Java SE and start the server RMI??

Thank you!

Comment: isn't GAE running on servlets? RMI protocol to y understanding cannot be deployed on a servlet.

Comment: Você pode me mostrar um exemplo? Penso que, como RMI é um servidor tenho que executar sempre, é possível fazer isso com servelet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google App engine doesn't support neither RMI protocol nor its libraries. GAE is PaaS, meaning you'll never get to modify the server environment. You'll have to adjust your solution to their platform.

Comment: The point is not to modify the environment, and I know that GAE is PaaS. I've read in several places that GAE does not support RMI, but because it appears in your white-list?

Comment: The environment is the whole point. RMI needs the java.rmi packages on both client and servers. You just can't add those libraries to the GAE. Also, servlets use HTTP protocol, and it's not compatible with neither JRMP nor IIOP (the RMI protocols), so implementing the protocol yourself over Servlets its out of the question.

Comment: Are you using GAE because of the free instances? If so, you can easily set up a free small server on Amazon and set up a RMI server.

Comment: I thought that because being in white-list could be implemented, for what I did I can only use servlets. A doubt, amazon offers free relational database as well? Thanks for the help.

Comment: You can set up an embedded Derby database in your server app, so you wont need an external one. It all can reside in a small amazon server instance, if it's only a small project.

Comment: Actually, amazon offers relational databases in the free tier. Have a look http://aws.amazon.com/es/free/

Comment: I am working for my academy, but I do not want to install servers on my machine. But I can not configure Primefaces + JSF + GAE. 'll See the Amazon site, I am grateful for your help!